# Can I Access the Azure AD tenant id in Terraform Resource

Tags: active-directory, terraform

I am trying to build a Key Vault resource and associate to my service principal in azure. I am working through the required fields and I need to provide my Azure AD Tenant id where my service principal is registered. Is there an easy way to access this in a terraform file? Rather not use ENV vars.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out. Terraform has an option to generate a data object.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/client_config.html

main.tf file

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
```

usage

```
tenant_id = "${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}"
```